# Postgres sql function that returns results of a join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, stored-procedures

In a postgres function (plain SQL not plpgsql) how can I return the result of a join between `table1` and `table2`? If the function definition has `returns setof table1` or `returns setof table2` it won't work because it's joining the two tables. And I get an error if I do `returns setof record`.

There are many columns in each of the tables so I'd like to avoid having to specify each of them in `table()` because it would be a maintenance nightmare keeping it up to date with schema changes.

Comment: Use `view` instead. Remember that you will should to recreate it each time when involved table(s) have been altered. If you want to wrap it into a function - use `returns setof view_name`.

Comment: @Abelisto: This comment should be the accepted *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I see: view and composite type.

Playground:

```
create table foo(foo_id int primary key, x text);
create table bar(bar_id int primary key, bar_foo_id int references foo(foo_id), y text);
insert into foo values(1, 'a'); insert into bar values(1,1,'b');
```

You could to create view and use it instead of a function:

```
create or replace view foobar as select * from foo join bar on foo_id = bar_foo_id;
select * from foobar where x = 'a' and y = 'b';
```

If you want to wrap it into a function then use view name as returning type:

```
create function foobar_fn(px text, py text) returns setof foobar language sql as $$
select * from foobar where x like px and y like py $$;
```

Disadvantages:

- Columns names should be distinct in all tables involved
- You should to recreate the view each time when tables structure have been altered

Another way - using composite type as returning type:

```
create function foobar_fn_1(px text, py text) returns table (tfoo foo, tbar bar) language sql as $$
select foo, bar  from foo join bar on foo_id = bar_foo_id where x like px and y like py $$;
```

This function returns two columns one of it contains `foo` table data and another contains `bar` table data:

```
postgres=# select * from foobar_fn_1('a','b');
┌───────┬─────────┐
│ tfoo  │  tbar   │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│ (1,a) │ (1,1,b) │
└───────┴─────────┘
```

You could to expand all of it or access each field individually:

```
postgres=# select (tfoo).*, (tbar).*, (tfoo).x, (tbar).y from foobar_fn_1('a','b');
┌────────┬───┬────────┬────────────┬───┬───┬───┐
│ foo_id │ x │ bar_id │ bar_foo_id │ y │ x │ y │
╞════════╪═══╪════════╪════════════╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
│      1 │ a │      1 │          1 │ b │ a │ b │
└────────┴───┴────────┴────────────┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Note about parenthesis around columns.